# Getting empty objects in response json (SpringBoot)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

While calling /employee/swipe/all api getting empty objects in response:

[image]

Other endpoints like /employee/getAll are working fine:

[image]

Below are the entity and controller classes:

Employee:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Swipes:

```
@Entity
public class Swipe {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @ManyToOne private Employee employee;
    private LocalDateTime swipeInTime;

    public Swipe(){}

    public Swipe(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.swipeInTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public Swipe(Employee employee, LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.swipeInTime = localDateTime;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/employee")
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @Autowired private SwipeService swipeService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/getAll")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAll() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeService.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getAll(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                employeeService
                        .findById(id)
                        .orElseThrow(
                                () ->
                                        new DataNotFoundException(
                                                "Employee not found for id: " + id)),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }

// this one is returning empty objects in json
    @GetMapping(path = "/swipe/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Swipe>> getAllSwipes() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(swipeService.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

While debugging the code I can see the swipeService is returning the details as expected. Any help will be appreciated . Thanks !

Comment: try adding getter and setter for Swipe entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your solution to the Swipes entity class and it will solve the empty fields.

```
@Entity
public class Swipe {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;
private LocalDateTime swipeInTime;

public Swipe(){}

public Swipe(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
    this.swipeInTime = LocalDateTime.now();
}

public Swipe(Employee employee, LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    this.employee = employee;
    this.swipeInTime = localDateTime;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public LocalDateTime getSwipeInTime() {
    return swipeInTime;
}

public void setSwipeInTime(LocalDateTime swipeInTime) {
    this.swipeInTime = swipeInTime;
}
```

}